# DBContext Not Being Disposed on Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simple-injector

I have the following Registration in Simple Injector 3.1.0:

```
container.RegisterForWeb<AppContext>(() => new EFAppContext(
    @"DefaultConnection", 
    new PetaPocoDispatcher(@"DefaultConnection")));
```

Inside this RegisterForWeb method i have:

```
var hybridLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    () => HttpContext.Current != null,
    new WebRequestLifestyle(),
    new LifetimeScopeLifestyle());

container.Register<TService>(instance, hybridLifestyle);
```

My `EFAppContext` Class is an extensions of `IdentityDbContext`

```
public class EFAppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, 
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>, 
    AppContext
{
    ...
}
```

And i Followed the tutorial to find Leaking Connections on EF6 [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823951/Finding-Non-disposed-Contexts-in-Entity-Framework). And Extended this tutorial to be able to see which Query was being executed by this leaked connection. And I found that every time i made a request to the Server, a new connection was being open and never closed. And the only query it did was:

```sql
IF db_id(N'DB_MySystem_TEST') IS NOT NULL 
    SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE [name]=N'DB_MySystem_TEST'
```

Is this a problem with my code, or with Simple Injector? I had never had this problem with Simple Injector 2.8.0.

Comment: Since you use the `LifetimeScopeLifestyle`, please show the code you use to start a lifetime scope.

Comment: @Steven , In the example I gave, I'm doing Web requests, so I'll use WebRequestLifestyle.

Comment: In that case, please use the `WebRequestLifestyle` instead of a hybrid lifestyle and check again whether the problem remains.

Comment: @Steven, in the code i posted, it checks to verify if it is a Web request or not and use the appropriate LifeStyle. EitherWay, i tried to HardCode WebRequestLifeStyle and I got the Same problem.

Comment: Simple Injector will guarantee to dispose WebRequestLifestyle registrations automatically when the web request ends. In other words, you can be quite certain that `EFAppContext` is disposed, so the problem is probably somewhere else. But if in doubt, do override `Dispose` in your `EFAppContext` and set a breakpoint in both the constructor and the dispose method to verify whether each instance is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

My `EFAppContext` Class had a Constructor that verified every Time if the Database Exists:

```
public class EFAppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, 
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>, 
    AppContext
{
    if (!this.Database.Exists())
        this.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    ...
}
```

And I don´t know why it Forced my connection to stay opened. So I Wrapped it with a Transaction:

```
public class EFAppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, 
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>, 
    AppContext
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = this.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.Database.Exists())
                this.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            dbContextTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And Now It my connection is disposed. The only question that remains is why...

Comment: 'using' is a syntactic sugar which always calls Dispose() method.

Comment: I suspect that connections created in the `IdentityDbContext`'s constructor are not closed properly. The root of your problems however is that [your constructor is not simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). This creation logic should not be placed inside the constructor. Since you only want to do this once at application startup, you should move this logic out of the `EFAppContext` class and into your application startup code, directly after you registered and verified the container. This also makes it clear to anyone reading the code what's going on.